# android studio lint doen't check implementation version of class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lint

I can't configure android lint in android studio to check if some android class doesn't implement interface on one of android version.

For example, I have an application with these parameters

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode ...
        versionName ...
    }
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

And I have a source code like this:

```
private List<String> getValues() {
    List<String> locations = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        inputStream = service.openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        locations = getValues(scanner);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
        Utils.catchException(exc, LOG_TAG);
    } finally {
        Utils.closeStreams(LOG_TAG, scanner, inputStream);
    }
    return locations;
}

...

class Utils {
    ...
    public static void closeStreams(String tagName, Closeable... streams) {
        for (Closeable stream : streams) {
            closeStream(stream, tagName);
        }
    }
}
```

So here I have a compatibility issue that the Scanner class implements Closeable only in API 19. But my min API is 10. So I propose that android lint should tell me about this problem.

But it doesn't. Can't understand what option to select in android studio inspections settings to find this type of problem.
I only found 'Calling new methods on older versions' but it doesn't work for this problem.